# AWS EC2 instances without NUMA support

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, numa

I am looking to create EC2 instances without NUMA architecture. Windows docs say, OS will create multiple nodes if no. of logical processors are more than 64. However, i tried creating instances with 64 and 48 cores but OS is creating multiple NUMA nodes. My OS is windows 2012 R2 x64.

Is there some way I can disable NUMA architecture on EC2 instances or are there any instances types with more than 36 logical processors which do not create multiple NUMA nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Windows displays multiple NUMA nodes, this is reflecting the underlying hardware. It's not possible to disable NUMA--either the instance type has multiple physical CPU sockets, each with their own DRAM slots, or it doesn't. That is what NUMA (Non-Uniform Memory Access) means. Depending on what core a process is running on, some areas of memory are slower to access, because the request has to leave the socket, travel over QPI to another socket, be acted on, and the response sent back over QPI.

As I write this, the largest EC2 instances with a single NUMA node are [m5.12xlarge](https://instaguide.io/info.html?type=m5.12xlarge#tab=lstopo), [m5d.12xlarge](https://instaguide.io/info.html?type=m5d.12xlarge#tab=lstopo), [r5.12xlarge](https://instaguide.io/info.html?type=r5.12xlarge#tab=lstopo), and [r5d.12xlarge](https://instaguide.io/info.html?type=r5d.12xlarge#tab=lstopo). Each has 48 vCPUs from a single Xeon Platinum 8175.

P.S. On systems with more than 64 cores, Windows does create multiple [processor groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/processor-groups), but this is different from a NUMA node. Processor groups are a workaround for a limitation in Windows, not related to hardware, but still--they exist, or not. Windows needs processor groups to work correctly, and they can't be disabled.

Comment: I tried with m4.16xlarge (#64 CPU) and m5a.12xlarge (#48 CPU) but 2 CPU groups were created but I was hoping there will be a single group. I haven't tried with any of the instance types you mentioned but how are they different from the one's I mentioned. Is there some thing in the documentation which says that for the one's you mentioned there will be a single group.

Comment: m4 and m5a instances use different processors with fewer cores per NUMA node. AWS doesn't provide documentation on this, but [the site linked in my answer](https://instaguide.io/) does. For any instance type on the site, you can click "Topology" and see a display of the system layout, with cores grouped into NUMA nodes.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.